# Using Python Django how could I do custom function, save to db and return json response

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I created a scraper and want to integrate it with API. Starting with Python Django is great and offers easy start, but I am having trouble with the following structure of code:

GET request on /test

1. Scrape data
2. Save data to db
3. Return data as a response

Basically I am having trouble with saving data of a list in database and returning that data as response. Scraper would be in another python file in utils.py and api would call a function and it would return list of scraped data

Does anyone have an example of what I am trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You might use a [custom django-admin command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-management-commands/). You might be able to access all of your models as if you were developing a view. And you can trigger your command with `./manage.py mycustomcommand`.